# Windows 8: recovering a saved auto-login password (netplwiz)

Tags: windows, windows-8, passwords, password-recovery

A couple of months ago, I've installed Windows 8 on a laptop of my mom. I created a Microsoft account for her, and used some tutorial to enable auto-login with `netplwiz`, so she won't have to enter the password every time.

So far so good, everything works as expected, but I just needed her password for something, and I realized that I forgot which password I chose for her.

Is there any way to recover the saved password from the computer?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to reset the password to the `Microsoft Account` and select a new password.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't have a win8 machine to hand to check, but I am pretty sure that passwords are stores in what is known as an LSA Secret.

LSA secrets are stored, encrypted in a registry key at: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Security\Policy\Secrets  - However, thee are not readable as they are hidden from the traditional Regedit program

If you google "decrypt LSA secrets" and "view LSA secrets" etc, there are a whole hoard of tools out there which will allow you to decrypt and view this password.

Of course, as Ramhound says - it may just be simpler to reset the password, assuming you have the ability to do so.